# Get lowercase tag names with xmldom.XMLSerializer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

I'm using Node.js to save a D3 graph to a file. The code is returning the SVG tags as all-caps instead of lowercase tags:

```xml
<SVG height="300" width="460" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <G transform="translate(230,150)">
            <PATH d="M6.123031769111886e-15,-100A100,100 0 0,1 90.12430862004372,43.33138580473872L45.06215431002186,21.66569290236936A50,50 0 0,0 3.061515884555943e-15,-50Z" fill="#1f77b4"/>
            <PATH d="M90.12430862004372,43.33138580473872A100,100 0 0,1 4.27399232527422,99.90862319941907L2.13699616263711,49.954311599709534A50,50 0 0,0 45.06215431002186,21.66569290236936Z" fill="#aec7e8"/>
            <PATH d="M4.27399232527422,99.90862319941907A100,100 0 0,1 -64.73671010012329,76.21783495621347L-32.368355050061645,38.10891747810673A50,50 0 0,0 2.13699616263711,49.954311599709534Z" fill="#ff7f0e"/>
            <PATH d="M-64.73671010012329,76.21783495621347A100,100 0 0,1 -99.89978970073908,-4.4757142165364L-49.94989485036954,-2.2378571082682A50,50 0 0,0 -32.368355050061645,38.10891747810673Z" fill="#ffbb78"/>
            <PATH d="M-99.89978970073908,-4.4757142165364A100,100 0 0,1 -1.836909530733566e-14,-100L-9.18454765366783e-15,-50A50,50 0 0,0 -49.94989485036954,-2.2378571082682Z" fill="#2ca02c"/>
        </G>
    </SVG>
```

The node.js script:

```js
require('d3');
var xmldom = require('xmldom');

var dataset = {
    apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

var width = 460,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(dataset.apples))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color(i);
})
    .attr("d", arc);
var svgObject = d3.select("svg").attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
var xml = new xmldom.XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgObject[0][0]);

console.log(xml);
```

How do you get the tag names as lowercase names (which SVG needs)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this lowerCase option does not seem to be supported right now by xmldom.

So you can either [ask for it on github](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom) or fork your own version of the module in the meantime.

You have to change this line to grab the lowercase version of the tag names :

https://github.com/jindw/xmldom/blob/master/dom.js#L919

Use

```
var nodeName = node.localName;
```

Instead of

```
var nodeName = node.tagName;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is really a string you want, you might try to use REGEXP, an example (now prevents lowercase in cdata):

```
function dom_string_lower(ds){
    var cd = {}, //var to backup cdata contents
        i = 0,//key integer to cdata token
        tk = String(new Date().getTime());//cdata to restore

    //backup cdata and attributes, after replace string by tokens
    ds = ds.replace(/\<!\[CDATA\[.*?\]\]\>|[=]["'].*?["']/g, function(a){
        var k = tk + "_" + (++i);
        cd[k] = a;
        return k;
    });

    //to lower xml/html tags
    ds = ds.replace(/\<([^>]|[^=])+([=]| |\>)/g, function(a, b){
        return String(a).toLowerCase();
    });

    //restore cdata contents
    for(var k in cd){
        ds = ds.replace(k, cd[k]);
    }

    cd = null;//Clean variable
    return ds;
}

var xml = new xmldom.XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgObject[0][0]);
console.log( dom_string_lower(xml) );

//test case
var test = "<SVG TITLE=\"ABC\"><ABC >A</ABC><test><![CDATA[TEST CASE]]></test></SVG>";
console.log( dom_string_lower(test) );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool. I ended up doing some specific regex for my graph output which changed those tags to lowercase. This may be a more forward-thinking version of that. I'm still holding out hope that using regex won't be needed to do this ... but we'll see!